# Which Version Control for Drupal?

Tags: svn, git, drupal, version-control

I am starting to need to work on bigger sites and with multiple people so I know I need to start using some kind of version control. GRRR.  While I understand and use Features and Context to put config info into code instead of the DB, I am still confused about what version control system I should use?  Is there any advantage to using GIT? or Subversion?  Especially in terms of workflow.

I am still pretty new to version control "conceptually" and practically so I am not even sure what I need to setup.  I'd like to be able to use version control locally as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to use version
>   control locally as well.

In that case use Git or some other [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Version_Control_System). SVN is centralized and will not allow you to make any local commits.

I would also suggest Git for the reasons listed [on whygitisbetterthanx.com](http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/) (branching and local commits), this however is subjective.

Comment: Another reason to use Git: Drupal.org is moving to Git.

Comment: Source control is life changing for most developers, and GIT is better than other options in so many ways you can't go wrong with either. Start using it and see where it works for you, and how it helps. Don't get bogged down in it however. . . it's a tool, not what you should 'actually' be working on.